# Email formatting basics (links in plain text emails)

Tags: html, css, email, hyperlink, html-email

Sending an email from a server isn't quite as easy as sending it from a client.

I know I can choose to send plain text or html, but I want to keep things as simple as possible.

I have a link in the email that the user should click to reset their password.

When I send the whole link, and check my gmail, it becomes a hyperlink automatically.

My guess is that this isn't the case in all email clients.

What are my options for sending a link in plain text format?

Is the only way to be sure to have a clickable link to use html?

If I use html, what is the minimum markup I must have?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you send your email in plain text, then your URL will be plain text. It's plain text, you can't dress it up.

If you send it as HTML, just use a simple anchor tag and use the URL as both the href and the text. That way if a mail client removes the link at least the user will still be able to copy/paste the url.

Answer (score 15):

Another option rather than simply including urls inline in your text is to use a markdown-ish syntax that allows you to separate the two.  For example, using citation-style link references (a la the way SO does it in this editor) could be done like so:

> ```
> Hello, this is a plain email that links to a [cool page][1].
>
> Sincerely,
> Joe
>
> [1]: http://foo.com/cool_page
> ```

I've seen it done this way and it works well, especially if you have a lot of links.

Comment: is this acceptable?

Answer (score 12):

There is a syntax similar to `angle-addr` as defined in [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4) and `mailto` URL Schema defined in [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368#section-6).

[RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4.3) mentions using angle brackets as delimiters around URI in text documents and protocol fields:

> The angle-bracket "<" and ">" and double-quote (") characters are
> excluded because they are often used as the delimiters around URI in
> text documents and protocol fields.  The character "#" is excluded
> because it is used to delimit a URI from a fragment identifier in URI
> references (Section 4). The percent character "%" is excluded because
> it is used for the encoding of escaped characters.

> delims      = "<" | ">" | "#" | "%" | <">

Example derived from real-world usage:

```
From: alpha@beta.com
To: theta@omega.com
Content-Type: text/plain

Some introduction text

The text I want to display in this link<https://some.target.dom/ain#place?i=want&to=go>

The rest of my plain text message
```

Comment: Have you tried this? This does not work in any of the mail clients I've tried. What client(s) does this work with? RFC2396 describes what you say, but that appears to be completely irrelevant to the question since it doesn't concern displaying a link?

Comment: This is not for clients, rather if you compose your eml file in plain-text and send to smtp gateway directly. On the receiving end, the client *should* interpret the RFC2369 sequence if the if the client properly implemented the specification. The specification is for indicating that a sequence of characters is a URI, such as a link.

Answer (score 1):

To send html emails you have to provide full structured html page with no relative links (only full urls) for any resources(images src, styles and href link attributes).

But text emails are good enough for their purposes, in web mail clients links are found in mails text by browser, and standalone mail clients do this work by themselves.